# Running additional service in Safe Mode win8.1

Tags: service, windows-8.1, regedit, safe-mode

The problem is I need to install the program, that runs additional service in the middle of installation. While trying to run it manually, it returns error 1084: Can not start the service in the Safe Mode.

What should I add to registry in order to run this service?

Comment: any update on the issue? Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

To start services in Safe mode you have to run `regedit.exe` and go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot`.

Windows has 2 types of safe mode. The minimal one and the one with network.

Under your type create now a key with the short name of your driver and type service in the default string. Here you can also whitelist other windows services / drivers that you want o get loaded in safe mode.